# batch file extra iteration into only one label

Tags: windows, batch-file

Sorry for the length but the error I'm getting, possibly, encompasses all of my code.

I've made two files, one(rngInputTest) starts and checks for execution looping and passes four variables to the second(rngCompare) file via parameters in the call command.

The second file then takes the four parameters and saves them to four variables local to rngCompare, then uses %random% twice. After that it sets the two new variables(rng1 and rng2) into compare var by adding them together and passes compare back to rngInputTest has a parameter which is saved to the var result.

rngInputTest then does a final check and if the checkLoop var is 2 it goes to the final label/function(rngInputTestDisplay),which works, it echoes result fine.

The problem I'm having is that ,without my workaround, somehow execution goes to rngInputTestDisplay a second time after rngInputTestDisplay is ran once(no other label/function is called and when rngInputTestDisplay is ran the second time it empties the result var)

My current workaround is

```
IF %checkLoop%==%logicIII% goto :end
```

I placed this at the beginning of rngInputTestDisplay and it stops the extra iteration.

Without the workaround,even after putting:

```
echo in [label]
pause
```

in all of the labels/functions,in rngInputTest and rngCompare, I still wasn't able to figure out how the extra iteration is occurring though I did notice that execution loops only to rngInputTestDisplay none of the earlier labels were executed.

The end goal for these two files is to create a re-usable random num gen,so that I can call the first one multiple-times and pass different sets of data to it then return that data back to the 'main' file. I know I could use %random% once and save myself the headache but after using it a bit it doesn't really feel that random

I've included both files below

rngInputTest.bat

```
@ECHO off
    ::increment the loop-check var
set /a checkLoop+=1
goto :initLoopCheck

    ::used to check for looping
:initLoopCheck

    ::before execution loops to rngCompare
set logicI=1 
    ::after execution loops back from rngCompare
set logicII=2 
    ::used in rngInputTestDisplay,phantom loop
set logicIII=3 

    ::starts the initial loop
IF %checkLoop%==%logicI% goto :rngInputTestInitVarSet

    ::checks if code has looped back from rngCompare.bat
IF %checkLoop%==%logicII% goto :logic

    ::sets all the non-increment variables
:rngInputTestInitVarSet

    ::min-max's for use in rngCompare.bat :randomGen
set minI=0
set maxI=50
set minII=0
set maxII=50
goto :logic

    ::checks to see how far checkLoop has incremented
:logic
IF %checkLoop%==%logicI% goto :rngInputTestPass
IF %checkLoop%==%logicII% goto :rngInputTestDisplay

    ::passes min-max's to rngCompare via parameters
:rngInputTestPass
set checkLoop+=1
call rngCompare.bat %minI% %minII% %maxI% %maxII%
goto :rngInputTestDisplay

:rngInputTestDisplay

    ::this IF is important
    ::without it the code would loop..only to 
    :: :rngInputTestDisplay
    ::which causes result to be empty
IF %checkLoop%==%logicIII% goto :end

set /a checkLoop+=1
set result=%~1
echo result:%result%
pause
:end
```

rngCompare.bat

```
@ECHO off
goto :rngCompareInitVarSet

::initial variable set
:rngCompareInitVarSet
set MaxI=0
set MaxII=0
set MinI=0
set MinII=0
set result=0
goto :afterPass

::after rngInputTestPass
:afterPass
set MinI=%~1
set MinII=%~2
set MaxI=%~3
set MaxII=%~4
goto :randomGen


::generate two random numbers
:randomGen
::gets two random numbers from the variables passed from rngInputTest.bat
set /a rngI=(%RANDOM%*%MaxI%/32768)+%MinI%
set /a rngII=(%RANDOM%*%MaxII%/32768)+%MinII%
goto :compareRNG

::add the two rng numbers
:compareRNG
::adds the two numbers together
set /a compare=%rngI%+%rngII%
goto :passToRNGInputTest

::pass the compare var back to rngInputTest
:passToRNGInputTest
call rngInputTest.bat %compare%
```

Comment: Ugh. You have recursion (A calls B which calls A). But I don't think that is what you want. "rngCompare.bat" shoud *return* (EXIT /B) back to the caller "rngInputTest.bat". It should *not* recursively CALL "rngInputTest.bat".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way too complicated.  You don't have to "pass" values back and forth.  You already are setting them in Environment Variables and the second batch file runs from the same environment so anything updated in one will be available to the other.

For example these two simple batch files will show you the values are available.

myFirst.bat

```
@echo off

set /a myVal1=1
set /a myVal2=2
set /a myVal3=3
set /a myVal4=4

call mySecond.bat

echo my updated values from second batch
echo %myVal1%
echo %myVal2%
echo %myVal3%
echo %myVal4%

pause
```

mySecond.bat

```
@echo off

echo my values created in first batch
echo %myVal1%
echo %myVal2%
echo %myVal3%
echo %myVal4%

set /a myVal1=%myVal1%+%Random%
set /a myVal2=%myVal2%+%Random%
set /a myVal3=%myVal3%+%Random%
set /a myVal4=%myVal4%+%Random%

pause
```

If you call the second one more than once, just let it end, don't call the first file again.  When the second bat finishes it will return from the `Call` to the first file.

[image]

Comment: thanks I get it now, the thing that still stumps me is how the extra iteration is occurring. I'll definitely be testing that bit of info out later on today though